# implode causing invalid argument to show on admin sales emails

Tags: php, wordpress, implode

Anytime we have a sale without a coupon being used, I get an error on the email stating implode() invalid argument **functions.php**

It was not causing this issue, until recently, then I moved the website from one host to another and updated all the plugins.

The email function hooked that display the text

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_applied_coupons', 10, 4 );
```

```
function display_applied_coupons( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    // Only for admins and when there at least 1 coupon in the order
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && count($order->get_items('coupon') ) == 0 ) return;

    foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon->get_code();
    }
    // For one coupon
    if( count($coupon_codes) == 1 ){
        $coupon_code = reset($coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Coupon Used: ').$coupon_code.'<p>';
    } 
    // For multiple coupons
    else {
        $coupon_codes = implode( ', ', $coupon_codes);
        echo '<p>'.__( 'Coupons Used: ').$coupon_codes.'<p>';
    }
}
```

If the customer does not use a coupon it either should be blank or state "No Coupon Used" - I am not sure why the multiple coupons area is causing the section when they do not use any coupons.

Instead of it working I keep just getting this invalid argument to implode error

Comment: Just declare `$coupon_codes` as an array before foreach loop and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array_push instead of `$coupon_codes[]`

```
$coupon_codes = array();
foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ){
      //$coupon_codes[] = $coupon->get_code();
      array_push($coupon_codes,$coupon->get_code());//changes
}
```

some hosts are not supporting `[]` in array creatation.